# Algorithm to find the next value that results in a different "decomposition" (as per another function)

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I am trying to code an algorithm that will take an input value (an integer), and give me the next value that would result in a different decomposition/output from a different function. My current solution just uses that other function and checks each successive integer against it until the output changes, which I am trying to avoid as it is quite slow, and I am sure there is an efficient solution that incorporates some knowledge about the function to avoid having to try a bunch of inputs.

The function I have compares the input integer against a constant list/array of integers. These values in the list represent the cost of different "tiers" of an item and are arranged in ascending order. For the purpose of the solution it should be assumed that there is no relation between these values other than that they are strictly ascending, e.g. `[23, 105, 1042, 30054, ...]`. The input integer is treated as a currency and is decomposed into a list of item tiers that can be bought using that amount of the currency, starting with the highest tiers that can be afforded first. As an example, given the list of tier costs `[5, 20, 100, 500, 2000]` and the input value 5316, the output would be the list `[5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1]` (this output is in the form of the "tier number" (basically the position of the element in the tier cost list), but the form it ends up in isn't really important for the purpose of the algorithm I'm trying to develop anyway (it could output `[2000, 2000, 500, 500, 100, 100, 100, 5, 5, 5]` or have the list in a different order and that wouldn't change how the algorithm would function).

So given that that's the function I'm working with, I'm trying to find an efficient way to calculate the next integer that would give a different output if run through that function. Using the example above (an input of 5316 and above tier cost list), the algorithm should return 5320, since that value would be the first to output `[5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2]` from the above function, and no integers between 5316-5319 would output anything different from 5316.

If a code example would help, here is my current implementation of the above function for generating the list of tiers that can currently be afforded using Haskell:

```
powerFlowerCosts = [1940320,8108896,30577504,101946208,320015200,978185056,2956657504,8896037728,26718141280,80188414816,240603198304,721851511648,2165600414560,6496851086176,19490607063904]

emcToPowerFlowers :: Integer -> [Int]
emcToPowerFlowers curEMC = foldPFCs (reverse $ takeWhile (<= curEMC) powerFlowerCosts) curEMC
    where
        foldPFCs :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [Int]
        foldPFCs (pfc:pfcs) curEMC = foldPFCs pfcs (curEMC `rem` pfc)
          ++ replicate (fromInteger (curEMC `div` pfc)) (length pfcs + 1)
        foldPFCs [] _ = []
```

It first takes the list of tiers up to the last one that can be afforded, reverses the list, and then takes items off the list one at a time, adding that tier to the output however many times that tier can be afforded.

Comment: As you iterate through the list of prices, also store the additional money needed to buy one more of that tier than can be afforded. Take the min of that list and add it to the original budget.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is monotonic, you can use [binary search](https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/binary-search) to improve the efficiency. Take an interval `[l,r]` where `l` is the input and `r` is a big enough number which you know would have different output than `l` with given function. Keep shrinking the range until it's length is greater than 2 while maintaining invariant such that `l` always gives same output as input and `r` gives different output than `l`.

Here's pseudocode :

```
search f l r
    | r - l == 1 = r
    | f l == f mid = search f mid r
    | otherwise = search f l mid
        where mid = (l+r)/2
```